# How to display Html result from a Result type in elm?

Tags: elm

I have defined a simple `serverResponse` to simulate a response from an api to parse in elm-lang.

I am having issue going from a `Result` to showing a HTML of the information!

What is the best way to do this ?

```
import String exposing (..)

import String exposing (..)
import List exposing (..)

import Result exposing (map)

import Json.Decode as Json exposing (..)

type alias Team =
  { department : String
  , names: List String
  }

serverResponse = 
  """ 
  [{"department":"product","names":["bob","sally","george"]},{"department":"marketing","names":["billy","diane","anita"]},{"department":"sales","names":["howard","steve","isha"]}]
  """

stringDecoder = 
  Json.list Json.string

infoDecoder : Json.Decoder Team
infoDecoder =
    Json.map2 Team
      (Json.field "department" Json.string)
      (Json.field "names" stringDecoder)

teamDecoder : Json.Decoder (List Team)
teamDecoder = 
  Json.list infoDecoder

toList team = 
  p [] [
    team.department
    ]   

transformList teams = 
      toList teams

main = 
  Json.decodeString teamDecoder serverResponse
  |> toString 
  |> text
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `case` statement to extract the results of the decoding. This allows you to explicitly handle both the success and failure of a decoder.

Your `main` function can be changed to the following (Note that I have redefined `toList` because you weren't returning valid Html):

```elm
toList : Team -> Html msg
toList team = 
  p [] [ text team.department ]   

main = 
  case Json.decodeString teamDecoder serverResponse of
      Ok teams ->
          div [] (List.map toList teams)

      Err msg ->
          text ("ERROR: " ++ msg)
```

[`Result`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.0.0/Result#Result) is a union type with two constructors: `Ok` and `Err`. You can read up on [union types in the Elm Guide](https://guide.elm-lang.org/types/union_types.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is also [`withDefault`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Result#withDefault) for quick checking

```
Result.withDefault 0 (String.toInt "123") == 123
```